# cannot convert from 'System.IO.TextWriter' to 'System.IO.Stream'

Tags: c#

```
        var ssh = new SshClient("ip", "user", "pass");
        var input = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("exit\r\n"));

        var shell = ssh.CreateShell(input, Console.Out, Console.Out, "xterm", 80, 24, 800, 600, "");
        shell.Stopped += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nDisconnected...");
        };
        shell.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000 * 1000);
        shell.Stop();
```

error on this line :

```
var shell = ssh.CreateShell(input, Console.Out, Console.Out, "xterm", 80, 24, 800, 600, "");
```

Errors :
Error   3   Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.IO.TextWriter' to 'System.IO.Stream'    D:\applications area\test\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs    19  48  ConsoleApplication1

Error   4   Argument 3: cannot convert from 'System.IO.TextWriter' to 'System.IO.Stream'    D:\applications area\test\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs    19  61  ConsoleApplication1

any solution ?

Comment: We need to know what lines are what to align your error messages with your code

Comment: Whatever `SshClient` is (you don't say), its `CreateShell` method accepts a `Stream` as either its second or third parameters, or both, and you're not passing it that. `TextWriter` (the type of `Console.Out`) doesn't inherit from `Stream`.

Answer (score 5):

`Console.Out` is a `TextWriter`, not a stream.

Try something like this (warning: compiled in head)

```
Stream stdout = Console.OpenStandardOutput();
var ssh = new SshClient("ip", "user", "pass");
var input = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("exit\r\n"));

var shell = ssh.CreateShell(input, stdout, stdout, "xterm", 80, 24, 800, 600, "");
shell.Stopped += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nDisconnected...");
};
shell.Start();
Thread.Sleep(1000 * 1000);
shell.Stop();
```

Though note that passing it twice seems wrong. You probably want to pass in something else for either the second or third parameter to `ssh.CreateShell`. Probably `Console.OpenStandardInput()`, for that matter.

Comment: As a note: If this is the ssh client lib from codeplex then `CreateShell` takes two output streams as parameters, one `output` and one `extendedOutput` (whatever that is). So passing `stdout` twice is probably ok and passing `stdin` might be a bad idea.